# Fixing space before and after multicol

Tags: spacing, multicol

I want to use the `multicol` package in order to have two lists side by side. The problem is that using it creates unwanted space *above* and *below* the environment.

For instance, compare the outcome of this...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem}
\setlength\parindent{0em}

\begin{document}
    \textbf{Some nice list}
    
    Here is the nice list:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Some item
    \end{itemize}
    Wasn't it nice?
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

... to the one of this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem}
\setlength\parindent{0em}

\begin{document}
    \textbf{Some nice lists}
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        Here is one nice list:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Some item
        \end{itemize}
        
        Here is another nice list:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Some other item
        \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}
    Weren't the lists nice?
\end{document}
```

[image: 2]

Adding `\setlength{\multicolsep}{0.0pt}` fixes the issue with the space above, but then the space below is too small.

How can this problem be fixed in a nice way? I am not wanting to adjust the spaces manually (using some `\vspace`).

Comment: One solution is to use paracol instead of multicol.  Another is to add `\hrule height0pt` after each itemize, or place each itemize inside a `\parbox{\linewidth}{...}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you, I like the solution using paracol best.