# How to fix spacing after multicols with lstlisting?

Tags: spacing, listings, multicol

When combining `lstlisting` with `multicols` inside a `minipage` or `tcolorbox`, the vertical spacing of `lstlisting` changes. The spacing on top can be fixed by using `\topskip = 0pt` (see this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487968/108208) with a remaining question for the bottom spacing), but the spacing at the bottom is mostly incorrect. The best approximation is obtained for `belowskip = 0pt` and an even number of lines. Setting `belowskip > 0pt` gives the same wrong spacing (which depends on the font size) for each number of lines.

Is there a general fix for this issue? And if there isn't one, what is the best practice to get consistent spacing?

**Example**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}

% Simplified tcolorbox
\newenvironment{mybox}{
    \addvspace{\bigskipamount}
    \hrule
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
}{
    \end{minipage}
    \hrule
    \addvspace{\bigskipamount}
}

\parindent = 0pt

\begin{document}
Normal

\verb|belowskip = 0pt|

\begin{mybox}
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip = 0pt, belowskip = 0pt]
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mybox}

\begingroup
\huge
\begin{mybox}
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip = 0pt, belowskip = 0pt]
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mybox}
\endgroup

Multicols

\verb|belowskip = 0pt|

\topskip = 0pt

\begin{mybox}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip = 0pt, belowskip = 0pt]
Ag
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multicols}
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip = 0pt, belowskip = 0pt]
Ag
Ag
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multicols}
\end{mybox}

Multicols with default settings of listings

\verb|belowskip = \medskipamount > 0pt|

\begin{mybox}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}
Ag
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multicols}
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}
Ag
Ag
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multicols}
\end{mybox}

\begingroup
\huge
\begin{mybox}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}
Ag
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multicols}
\end{mybox}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

**Update**

The normal spacing of `listings` is introduced by `\lsthk@EveryLine` (hook EveryLine). This can be imitated with `\par` and `\strut`. Adding `\vspace` is similar to `belowskip`. So the spacing behaviour can be reduced to `multicol`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}

% Simplified tcolorbox
\newenvironment{mybox}{
    \addvspace{\bigskipamount}
    \hrule
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
}{
    \end{minipage}
    \hrule
    \addvspace{\bigskipamount}
}

\parindent = 0pt

\begin{document}
Normal

\begin{mybox}
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip = 0pt, belowskip = 0pt]
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip = 0pt, belowskip = 0pt]
Ag
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mybox}

Imitation of lstlisting

\begin{mybox}
\par\strut Ag
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
\par\strut Ag
\par\strut Ag
\end{mybox}

Multicols with imitation of lstlisting

\topskip = 0pt

\begin{mybox}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\par\strut Ag
\par\strut Ag
%\vspace{0pt}% no belowskip
\end{multicols}
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\par\strut Ag
\par\strut Ag
\vspace{0pt}% belowskip --> reduces the deviation to a small value, but the spacing remains incorrect
\end{multicols}
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\par\strut Ag
\par\strut Ag
\par\strut Ag
\vspace{0pt}% belowskip
\end{multicols}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Minipage is supposed to re;move gaps at the top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an odd number of lines, the bottom of first column will be even with the baseline.  It doesn't matter what belowskip is because is won't be at the bottom of the column.  It is possible that multicols would normally add some space itself, but the minipage eats it.  (`\@minipagefalse` is worse.)

It is not clear how much gap one should add below the baseline.  `\dp\strutbox` is too small, and `\medskipamount` is too large.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}

\parindent = 0pt

\begin{document}
Normal

\verb|belowskip = 0pt|\bigskip

\hrule
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip = 0pt, belowskip = 0pt]
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\hrule
\bigskip

Multicols

\verb|belowskip = 0pt|\bigskip

\topskip = 0pt

\hrule
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip = 0pt, belowskip = 0pt]
Ag
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}
\hrule
\bigskip

\hrule
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip = 0pt, belowskip = 0pt]
Ag
Ag
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multicols}
\vskip 1ex
\hrule height0pt
\end{minipage}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: Playing with the length (`\vspace{1ex}` works also without need of `\hrule`) gives an acceptable result, but it isn't a general fix. The spacing depends also on the font size (I've updated the MWE). For `\huge`, there is already some space below the baseline.

Answer (score 0):

This fix is based on the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650830/fixing-space-before-and-after-multicol#comment1622212_650830) of @John Kormylo to another question. The space after each line can be protected by adding `\hrule height0pt` at the end.

```
\begin{mybox}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\par\strut Ag\hrule height0pt
\par\strut Ag\hrule height0pt
\par\strut Ag\hrule height0pt
\vspace{0pt}% belowskip
\end{multicols}
\end{mybox}
```

Fortunately, `listings` contains the hook `\lst@AddToHook{EOL}` to do this task (see [listings-devel.pdf](https://mirror.lyrahosting.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings-devel.pdf)). Note that this hook must be cleared after each `lstlisting` because the same code will be added each time `lstlisting` is called. It also prevents unwanted effects to other listings (`\lstinline{code}` for example).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}

% Simplified tcolorbox
\newenvironment{mybox}{
    \addvspace{\bigskipamount}
    \hrule
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
}{
    \end{minipage}
    \hrule
    \addvspace{\bigskipamount}
}

\makeatletter
% Simplified tcolorbox with multicols
\newenvironment{multibox}[1][2]{
    \topskip = 0pt% remove spacing on top
    \begin{mybox}
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
    \lst@AddToHook{EOL}{\hrule height0pt}% add hrule after each input line
}{
    \end{multicols}
    \end{mybox}
}

% Clear the hook
\AfterEndEnvironment{multibox}{\gdef\lsthk@EOL{}}
\makeatother

% Set the skips of lstlisting to 0pt
\lstset{aboveskip = 0pt, belowskip = 0pt}

\parindent = 0pt

\begin{document}
Normal

\begin{mybox}
\begin{lstlisting}
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
\begin{lstlisting}
Ag
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mybox}

Multicols

\begin{multibox}
\begin{lstlisting}
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multibox}

\begin{multibox}
\begin{lstlisting}
Ag
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multibox}

\begin{multibox}
\begin{lstlisting}
Ag
Ag
Ag
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multibox}
\end{document}
```

[image]